# Tar files that were modified in the last 2 days

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to tar all the files in my downloads folder that was changed in the last 2 days. When I execute the below, it instead tar's **all** the files inside my Downloads folder

```
find ~/Downloads -mtime 2 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cvfz test.tar.gz
```

Comment: The `tar` command here will not work with the hyphen. Remove it, as otherwise the file created will `z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -mtime -2, to tar all the files with less of two days.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but avoid "Try..." answers. They appear to the questioner that you are unsure if what you are suggesting will work and they should just "try" it and see if it does. Also, for a complete answer, you should discuss how the 24-hour periods are specified for the `-mtime` test (as with the `-atime` and `-ctime` tests) where the time period is specified by `n * 24 hour periods` If `n` is specified it means exactly that long ago, while `-n` means anytime within that number of 24 hour periods and `+n` means older-than `n` 24-hour periods.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `find ~/Downloads/*` instead of `find ~/Downloads` as `find ~/Downloads` will also return the parent folder `~/Downloads` which results in the whole folder being archived, not only the changed files.

Comment: A better fix is to add `-type f` to only find files, not directories.

Comment: I've added this approach as this will also tar directories that got changed within the last 2 days. If only files should be archived, then your fix is definitely better.